# Bootstrap 3 table-responsive not scrolling on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table responsive but isn't working on mobile devices. I only get to see the first 2 columns and it shows no scroll bar. It does work if I resize the browser on big screens. How could I fix this ? 
I have:

```
<div class="table-responsive" >
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Product</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                  <th>Remove from WH</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>    
        {% for item in wh %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.product }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
            <td>$ {{ item.price }} </td>
            <td>
            <form action="" method="POST">{%csrf_token%}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="{{item.itemid}}" name="ii"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{item.itemid}}" name="ii"> </button>
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>$ {{ sum }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>       
  </div>
```

According to bootstrap documentation it should work, but it doesn't. Thanks

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.table-responsive {
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 15px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;

-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar; 
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;         
 } }
```

I have tested on Android 2.3.3, Safari and Dolphin browsers

Comment: post the full table code

Comment: Define "mobile devices". What specific OSes and browsers (& versions)?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code for this, May be its an issue of overflow-hidden.